# How do I make the height of the input the same as the height of the text?

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the CSS options I've added for input:

```html
<input type="email" value="" name="user[email]" style="
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
">
```

But why is the input height higher as a result?

[image]

There are no other styles.

Can you please tell me how to make the input height exactly the same as the text?

Comment: can you post your code as text please? thanks!

Comment: @cornonthecob done

Comment: did you mean to comment out the height?

Comment: box-size: border-box? also, as you have set the font size, how about setting the line height explicitly to 36px?

Comment: @MohamedMufeed None of this helps

Comment: @Colibri If thats the case, try opening the developer tools(preferably chrome) and see the computed height and from where it is getting that extra height. most probably some thing else is affecting your styles

Comment: I suspect that `font-size: 36px` is causing the issue, can you tell me the font-size of the other text?

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behaviour of the input elements.
The Blinking cursor within, takes more height than the text within, that's why we have inner padding that doesn't go away.

[image]

See, the blinking cursor touches the **border-top** and **border-bottom**. And border-left has text touching it. So that's the default behaviour of input elements, there is going to be a small *padding-top* and *padding-bottom.*